# Seat count calculation to fill a row within 50mm

Tags: geometry

I have 3 sizes of seats measuring 510, 535, and 560. I also have extra seat arms measuring 50.  I want to use combinations of these seats and extra arms to fill a row within 50mm of its total length.  I also have an average seat size that I would like to achieve of 550. Lastly I would like to be able to choose an even or odd total seat count. I assume that most long (ie 10000) row lengths would have multiple solutions. How do I find them?

Answer (score 1):

It depends.  Do you want to find an optimal solution (for example, the solution with the fewest chairs), or do you want to find *all* solutions?

To find *all* solutions, the only real option is to use "brute force"--it would be best to write a computer program for this.

For finding the optimal solution greedy strategy could work (e.g. pick the biggest chair at each step, then proceed).  However, the validity of the greedy approach is dependent on how you define optimal.

For an arbitrary definition of *optimal solution*, I suggest Dynamic Programming (DP), which is too broad to completely cover here.  The idea of DP is very similar to recursion, but is more time and memory efficient.

Comment: Probably want to fit the most chairs, if it is a stadium or theater. :)

Comment: I really want to find the optimal solution. The one that fills the row (within 50mm), and is close to the right average (around 550). Right now I use a brute force method which works but takes more time to solve.